# Android: Is it Ok to use Fragment just for sake of ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am using ActionBar in my app but `for supporting lower API` I have used v7 support library. Now in order to use `getSupportActionBar()` (v7 actionbar support), I have to extend my class to `ActionBarActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Actually I am not using any feature of fragments like viewPager, tabs etc. I can actually do my work by simply extending `Activity`, but still have to use `ActionBarActivity` instead which is a direct derivative of `fragments`.

So is it okay to go for it ? I mean fragments do tend to use a bit more memory compared to simple activity, and my app is already bit high on memory usage so I am bit cautious in using this.

So do I have to continue in this way or can I try any other approach ?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: dont be afraid of fragments. they are a way to build apps on android platform and if not in this project you will use them for sure in others.

Comment: @pelotasplus, thnx for your reply, but I have already used fragments ahead in my app. But as here I didnt see any need of them and still had to use, caused me a doubt.